# I can't access GPS using Android 10 (API 29)

Tags: android

I use a code that worked fine with Android 4.1. But this code doesn't work any more with Android 10. The code is as follows :

```
LocationManager Objgps = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
Objlistener = new GPSlistener();
if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    // TODO: Consider calling
    //    Activity#requestPermissions
    // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
    //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
    //                                          int[] grantResults)
    // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
    // for Activity#requestPermissions for more details.
    return;
}
Objgps.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, Objlistener);
```

and :

```
private class GPSlistener implements LocationListener {
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    }

    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        Latitude.setText(CoordHrzSoleil.DDecToDMS(location.getLatitude()));
    }
}
```

and within the manifest :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
```

It seems that it misses some extra permissions, but I don't know what they are and how to apply them.

Thank you for your help.

Pierre.

Answer (score 0):

Well, finally, I found the (or a) solution ; it's the same kind of gymnastics as for writing / reading files:

In the manifest you must :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION"/>"
```

Then, in the code :

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
        if (checkPermission()) {
        } else {
            requestPermission(); // Code for permission
        }
    }
```

...

```
private boolean checkPermission() {
    if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
    && checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

private void requestPermission() {
    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MainActivity.this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
    && ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MainActivity.this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Access fine and coarse location allows us to use GPS. Please allow this permission in App Settings.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, GPS_PERMISSION_REQUEST);
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, GPS_PERMISSION_REQUEST);
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case GPS_PERMISSION_REQUEST:
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Log.e("value", "Permission Granted, Now you can use GPS .");
                } else {
                Log.e("value", "Permission Denied, You cannot use GPS .");
                }
            break;
    }
}
```

I haven't granted permission for "ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION". I'll have to check if it's necessary.

Cordially.

Pierre.